# JS function to count rows in SQLite table

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm trying to make a JS function that counts rows in an SQLite table.

```
function countRows(){
    db.transaction(function (tx){
        tx.executeSql('SELECT id FROM table', [], function (tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            alert(len);
        });
    });
}
```

The above code displays an alert with numbers of rows in the table. However, I'd like to make a function that would return the number instead of showing the alert box.

I tried:

```
function countRows(){
    db.transaction(function (tx){
        tx.executeSql('SELECT id FROM table', [], function (tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            return len;
        });
    });
}
```

And then:

```
var number = countRows();
alert (number); // returns "undefined"
```

The above example returns "undefined", whereas a parallel example works fine:

```
function count(){
    return 3;
}
var number = count();
alert (number); // returns 3
```

I want to assign the number to a variable, so I could then make another sql query, count rows in another table, and compare the two results.

In PHP this would be:

```
$sql1 = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1');
$rows1 = mysql_result($sql1, 0);
$sql2 = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2');
$rows2 = mysql_result($sql2, 0);
if ($row1>$row2){}
```

Answer (score 4):

You would be served much better by changing your query.

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM table
```

Plus, its an async call so that the call `return` is returning the callback function. You should pass your own callback function.

```
function countRows(callback){
    db.transaction(function (tx){
        tx.executeSql('SELECT id FROM table', [], function (tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            callback(len);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

db.transaction is asynchronous. returning value isn't assigned to any variable in code above. Solution is to pass callback or create custom event, which is almost the same.

Something like this:

```
function countRows(cb){
    db.transaction(function (tx){
        tx.executeSql('SELECT id FROM table', [], function (tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            cb.call(this, len);
        });
    });
}

countRows(function (num) {alert(num)});
```

Comment: Yours and Daniel's suggestions are very helpful, but they don't solve my problem. I see that using callback I can execute the function anywhere in the code, but that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to assign the value to a variable so I could count rows in two tables, then put the results in two different variables, and then compare the results using an if statement: if([NoOfRowsIn1stTable]>[NoOfRowsIn2ndTable]){}.

Comment: Why don't you use a global function called tblname and before you call countRows() do a tblName = "table1"; countRows(function (num) {alert(num)}); tblName="table2"; countRows(function (num) {alert(num)}); Inside the tx.executeSql would be : tx.executeSql('SELECT id FROM '+tblName, [], function (tx, results)

Comment: It's little ugly solution but it's easiest to implement. Idea is to pass "query function" for callback for each query expect last one. For last one pass a function that will compare results for previous queries. In this way you know that when executing one query, previous one is finished: countRowsTbl1(countRowsTbl2(callbackAfterBothQueriesAreExecuted));